# Problema ao renderizar o component que possui uma função no useEffect

Tags: javascript, react, funções, react-dom, slideshow

Criei em meu projeto um componente "Slide show" que possui a função abaixo para efetuar o slide automático. Porém, ao ir para outra página usando a função push do useHistory `history.push('/about');`, porem ao fazer isso, e voltar para a tela inicial que possui o "Slide Show", essa função do useEffect acaba sendo executada novamente, travando o slide.

**Como posso resolver isso?**

```
useEffect(() => {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".baner");
    var imagens = document.querySelectorAll(".bc_img img");
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".dots");

    function repeat() {
      let active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      let i = 1;
      var repeater = () => {
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(function () {
          [...active].forEach((activeSlide) => {
            activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
          });

          slides[i].classList.add("active");
          btns[i].classList.add("active");
          imagens[i].classList.add("active");
          i++;

          if (slides.length === i) {
            i = 0;
          }
          if (i >= slides.length) {
            return;
          }
          repeater();
        }, 5000);
      };
      repeater();
    }
    repeat();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `useEffect` pode ser desconsiderado se você retornar `false`. Você pode incluir uma checagem no início do `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(codicao) return false
}, [])
```